# How to Rotate and Resize an imageview with a button tapped using uitouch in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Hi I have a requirement where i need to resize and rotate the image view by dragging it right corner of the image view where there is a button.

I could successfully resize and rotate Individually  the image view by dragging its corner, but failed when i am trying to implement the resize cum rotate feature for the image view with one-finger.I am doing with UItouch delegate methods.

Please Suggest me....

Comment: [How To Enlarge UIImageView When Tapped](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9934031/1059705)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11431471/1059705

Comment: actually my aim is to rotate and scale the image at a time when we tapped the bottom right corner and moved on the screen.as like asked in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566791/how-to-rotate-and-resize-the-image-view-with-single-finger".

Comment: I too had same problem.I fixed that latter i have attached the sample code. pls refer my code in the below link.. [Sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fqfvd8gkrdkquv0/EAuBHflZoN/Resize%20and%20Rotate%20ImageView) Enjoy!!!!!

Comment: i am unable to get ur code pls attach once again.